# Прокси для сокета в perl

Tags: perl, proxy

Как мне в [моем коде](https://hastebin.com/ejosahepon.pl) добавить поддержку прокси?

```
socket($sock, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
connect($sock , sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($host)));
send($sock , "Hello" , 0);
close($sock);
```

Comment: В этот код - никак. Как минимум, нужно указать тип прокси, что собираетесь по ней передавать.

Comment: socks5 или http

Comment: так может и использовать LWP или курл?

Comment: Это не для http запросов, это для TCP запросов.

Comment: уже был такой вопрос - смотрите на протокол socks5 - он не сложен - нужно будет просто сокет открыть на сокс проки и ей уже передать данные, включая адрес подключения. либо берите на cpan что то готовое.

Comment: [Делов-то](https://metacpan.org/search?q=proxy+tcp) (ну или proxy+socks). А вообще причём тут Perl? Ручное велосипедостроительство как бы не приветствуется, почти для всех задач а перле есть готовые, отлаженные годами и миллионами пользователей, модули. Уж для вашей - точно.